# I'm trying to build site navigation using django-mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt

I've used django-mptt to model the sections and sub-sections etc of the headings I want to store my articles under. Some sections and sections will have children others won't.
 eg:

```
[Home]
 [News]
    [Politics][Crime][Policing]  etc 
 then [News] > [Politics]
                 [UKIP][Labour] etc
```

I'm sure you get the idea.
I've created the Section models

```
class Section(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True, related_name='sub_sections')
    tree = SectionTreeManager()
```

and by passing Section.objects.all() into the template :-

```
<ul class="headernav" >

    {% recursetree sections %}

        <li>
            <a href="/section/{{node.name}}" >{{ node.name }}</a>

             {% if node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul  class="headernav"> 
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
           </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

I can display all nodes. What I want to do is , based on the current url ie /section/News
 get all siblings on current level all ancestors on previous level and all related descendants on the level below. so if I selected News I'd get

```
[home][**News**][World][Sports][Culture] <- Level 0

[Politics][Crime][Education] <- Children on Level 1
```

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated. I'm learning Django so if it's obvious I apologise in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[django-page-cms](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms) has solved this type of problem using `django-mptt`, so I suggest having a look at the way it's done there.

Specifically, the [template to render the tree menu](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/blob/master/pages/templates/pages/dynamic_tree_menu.html) is recursively included via a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) called [`pages_dynamic_tree_menu`](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/blob/master/pages/templatetags/pages_tags.py#L225).

This sounds complicated (custom ta-whaaa!), so I'll  break it down a bit more.

We can consider a [`Page` in `django-page-cms`](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/blob/master/pages/models.py#L27) to be roughly the same as your `Section` class.

In the base template which is shared between 99% of your pages, `django-page-cms` [gets you to insert the following snippet](http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/navigation-template-tags.html#pages-dynamic-tree-menu):

```
<ul>
{% for page in pages_navigation %}
    {% pages_dynamic_tree_menu page %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`pages_navigation` [is set by](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/blob/master/pages/context_processors.py#L16) a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) (a way to add items to a  [template context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects) for all views in a django project) and contains the top level pages (i.e. those without parents).

The `pages_dynamic_tree_menu` tag is defined and registered as follows:

```
def pages_dynamic_tree_menu(context, page, url='/'):
    """
    Render a "dynamic" tree menu, with all nodes expanded which are either
    ancestors or the current page itself.

    Override ``pages/dynamic_tree_menu.html`` if you want to change the
    design.

    :param page: the current page
    :param url: not used anymore
    """
    lang = context.get('lang', pages_settings.PAGE_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)
    page = get_page_from_string_or_id(page, lang)
    children = None
    if page and 'current_page' in context:
        current_page = context['current_page']
        # if this node is expanded, we also have to render its children
        # a node is expanded if it is the current node or one of its ancestors
        if(page.tree_id == current_page.tree_id and
            page.lft <= current_page.lft and
            page.rght >= current_page.rght):
            children = page.get_children_for_frontend()
    context.update({'children': children, 'page': page})
    return context
    pages_dynamic_tree_menu = register.inclusion_tag(
        'pages/dynamic_tree_menu.html',
        takes_context=True
    )(pages_dynamic_tree_menu)
```

The whole point of it is to set the  `page` and the `children` variables.

The magic is in the `if` statement, which ensures the children are only displayed if the page is the current one (the `current_page` template variable is set by the `django-page-cms` view which renders a `Page`), or if the page is an ancestor. The `lft` & `rght` attributes are provided by `django-mptt`, and two of the properties of this MPTT are that *the left value of a parent tree node will be less than its child node's left value* and *the right value of a parent node will be more than the right value of its child node*, which you can verify visually by looking at the image below from the article [Trees in SQL](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html):

[image: picture of MPTT]

The `get_children_for_frontend()` method of `Page` calls `MPTTModel.getChildren()` with some filtering to hide unpublished `Page` objects, so nothing special there.

The tag then does the [tag equivalent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) of [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) with the [`pages/dynamic_tree_menu.html`](https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/blob/master/pages/templates/pages/dynamic_tree_menu.html) template, which in turn  calls the `pages_dynamic_tree_menu` tag again, causing the whole thing to recurse:

```
{% load pages_tags cache %}
{% if page.calculated_status %}
<li {% ifequal page current_page %}class="selected"{% endifequal %}>
<a href="{% show_absolute_url page %}">{% show_content page "title" %}</a>
{% if children %}
    <ul>{% for child in children %}{% pages_dynamic_tree_menu child url %}{% endfor %}</ul>
{% endif %}
</li>
{% endif %}
```

So if you define a similar setup (provide top level sections and the current section to your template, define an "inclusive" template tag and matching template for the tag) and apply some styling, then you should be able to use this approach to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Casper . Thanks Casper, that's a really clear easy to understand  explanation.  I'm at work at the moment I'll try it when I get back home tonight and get back to you. + 1

Comment: You're welcome. If this worked or was helpful, I would appreciate it if you accepted this answer (click the outline of a tick next to my answer)